# selectAll() and deselectAll() for checkboxlist causing issue

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist which is being populated dynamically from the database in the below way. Im using knockout here

this is fine , and the user can check and uncheck, whenever the user checks or unchecks the checkbox im using a click event and doing some calculations in the below way.

```
$('.options input:checkbox').click(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.is(':checked')) {
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

I also have `selectall` and `deselectall` buttons, and I'm doing that in the below way

select all function

```
$('.options').children('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if (!this.checked) {
    this.checked = true;
    }

});
```

deselect all

```
$('.options').children('input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
        var input = $(this);
        if (this.checked) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
});
```

The problem lies with the `selectall` and `deselectall`. Initially when the page loads, manually i select checkbox 1 and checkbox 3, then i click selectall button which makes all the checkboxes checked , then i select deselectall button which deselects all the checkboxes , the problem is here , after deselecting all when i manually click any checkbox it is also making checkbox 1 and checkbox 3 to be selected .

How can i resolve it?

Comment: shouldn't the condition be inside `if` statement, in case of **selectall**.   `if (!this.checked) { this.checked = true;}`

Comment: i have changed it, but still the issue is there.

Comment: Can you show the code of *manually selecting checkbox 1 and 3*

Comment: Its in the 2nd section in the above question i posted

Comment: Why are you using jQuery instead of knockout? The idea is you should be only editing the data in the model and then have the view update based on the model. You seem to be mixing the two here. Your selectAll and deselectAll should just loop through the model and change MyViewModeul.MyData.UsersChecked for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it in knockout:

http://jsfiddle.net/s86cm/

```
<div class="options" data-bind="foreach:users,visible: true" style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" class='roles' name='roles' data-bind="attr: { value: id }, checked:isChecked" />
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: selectAll">select all</button>
<button data-bind="click: deselectAll">delect all</button>

$(function() {
  var model = {
    users : [
        { id: 1, name: 'John', isChecked: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Max', isChecked: true },
        { id: 3, name: 'Adam', isChecked: true },
        { id: 4, name: 'Sam', isChecked: false },
    ]
  };

  var viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

function ViewModel(model) {
  var self = this;

  var users = $.map(model.users, function(user) { return new User(user) });

  self.users = users;

  var setIsChecked = function(isChecked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++){
        self.users[i].isChecked(isChecked);
    }
  };

  self.selectAll = function() {
    setIsChecked(true);
  };

  self.deselectAll = function() {
    setIsChecked(false);
  };
}

function User(user) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = user.id;
  self.name = user.name;
  self.isChecked = ko.observable(user.isChecked);
}
```